# How many records/objects are too many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am developing a browser based game in which users can buy and use various military units. Each unit would have different stats and health points, that will handle their behavior in battle, but would having like 500 units, each represented as it's own record in the DB be resource intensive?, or would it be better to have just one record, with an amount/number attribute. Problem with the last approach as I see it is that I can't treat each unit individually.

also, units won't be rendered graphically if that is of relevance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If 500 is the total number of units in the entire application, then it's not a problem.

If each player can have 500 units, the picture is different but it might still be ok.

If you need to load several hundreds of unit records for each HTTP request, then it's a completely different scenario. Depending on how many concurrent users you plan to have, it might be more than your DB can handle.